# Minimum of a list

Tags: list, function, loops, recursion, ocaml

I want to create a non-recursive function for my minimum
but I have some troubles with it
Can you help me please.

```
`let min_list lst=
    let n=list.length lst  ;;
    let a=list.nth lst ;;
    for i = 1 to n-1 ;;
    let b=list.nth lst i;;
    if a >b  then a=b lst done ;;`
```

Honesly,It's difficult with non recursive fonction.So this is just for learning.I still have erreur in ligne 6

```
let min_list lst=

    let a=List.hd lst in
    let n=List.length lst in
    for j =1 to n-1 do
    let b=List.nth lst j in
    if a > b then (let a=b) done ;;
```

Thank you it's useful It help me a lot .I have one other question what the difference between this

```
let min_array a =
  let min =ref (List.hd a) in
  for i = 1 to List.length a -1 do
    if List.nth a i < !min then min := List.nth a i
  done;
  !min;;
   print_int (min_array [ 10 ; 5 ; 7 ; 8 ; 12 ]);;
```

and

```
let min_array a =
  let min =ref (List.hd a) in
  for i = 1 to List.length a -1 do
    if ref (List.nth a i) < min then min := List.nth a i
  done;
  !min;;
   print_int (min_array [ 10 ; 5 ; 7 ; 8 ; 12 ]);;
```

It's the same ?I think

Comment: Start by taking a few steps back and learning basic ocaml syntax.

Comment: Not to be harsh, but @Shawn has a point since your code isn't even close to valid OCaml. Your main problems seem to be that (1) you believe the common rumor that `;;` is part of OCaml syntax (though in fact it's just a way to talk to the REPL), and (2) you're missing the `in`s that must be paired with each `let` inside a function.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you want to use a recursive function ?
Liste are made to be crossed by recursive function. Everytime you use `List.nth l n` Ocaml has to cross n values until he found the nth element.
In Ocaml you can't change variable value as you do in other languages. You want `a` to be a `ref`.
Also your function won't return anything you'll have to put a `!a` between the `done` and the `;;`. There will be a `!` Because `a` will be a ref.
But if you want to practice use arrays instead because what you do here is in complexity O(n²) instead of O(n).

Comment: Honesly,It's difficult with non recursive fonction.So this is just for learning.I still have erreur in ligne 6  >let min_list lst=
    let a=List.hd lst in
    let n=List.length lst in
    for j =1 to n-1 do
    let b=List.nth lst j in
    if a > b then (let a=b) done ;;

Answer (score 0):

As said in the answer from Butanium, this kind of non-recursive function might be more relevant with arrays. And to work with mutable values, you need to use a reference.

A solution might then be something like (without dealing with case of an empty array):

```ml
let min_array a =
  let min = ref a.(0) in
  for i = 1 to Array.length a -1 do
    if a.(i) < !min then min := a.(i)
  done;
  !min
```

The last line is important here, because it gets the value to be returned by the function.

Can then be used like that:

```
# min_array [| 10 ; 5 ; 7 ; 8 ; 12 |];;
- : int = 5
```

If you really do want to use lists instead of arrays, just use `List.nth a i` instead of `a.(i)` and `List.length` instead of `Array.length`.

#### Edit after question update

As Shawn and Jeffrey Scofield said in their respective comment, you should try to understand a bit better OCaml's syntax. And please don't use `;;` in your programs, just keep it for the REPL.

As described in the [documentation](https://ocaml.org/releases/4.10/htmlman/libref/Stdlib.html#TYPEref),
`ref` *returns a fresh reference containing the given value*.
Which means that when you write `ref (List.nth a i) < min`,
you create a fresh reference containing the i-th value the list, then compare it to `min` (which is also a reference). Luckily, [mutable structures are compared by contents](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/old_caml_site/ocaml/htmlman/libref/Pervasives.html#VAL(%3E=)), which means that OCaml will access to your fresh reference's value, then access to `min`'s value, and compare them. Thus, it will produce the same result as the direct comparison `List.nth a i < !min`, with a bit of useless memory allocation/access.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question. You want to know the difference between arrays and lists ?

Comment: sorry for some reasons I did not finish my  question . But I edit my publication. you can see the question clearly than here .thank you for your comprehension

Comment: @otakuforever i've added some answer to your new question. but as stated before, if you really need to avoid recursion, you should really use arrays instead of lists.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this quite concisely by taking advantage of some features of the OCaml stdlib:

```ml
(* 'a list -> 'a option *)
let min_list l =
  match l with
  | [] -> None
  | x::xs -> Some (List.fold_left min x xs)
```

Thanks to the `min` built-in, this works for lists of any type.

e.g. in a utop shell we can see:

```ml
min_list [99; 33; -1];;
- : int option = Some (-1)

min_list [99.1; 33.2; -1.3];;
- : float option = Some (-1.3)

min_list ["z"; "b"; "k"];;
- : string option = Some "b"
```

### Explanation

First we recognise that the list may be empty, in which case we cannot return a meaningful value. This implies the function should return an option type, so either `Some <value>` or `None`.

Next we can use `List.fold_left` to iterate through the list.

Unfortunately [the docs](https://ocaml.org/api/List.html#VALfold_left) for `List.fold_left` are almost completely unhelpful:

> `val fold_left : ('a -> 'b -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'b list -> 'a`
>
> > `fold_left f init [b1; ...; bn]` is `f (... (f (f init b1) b2) ...) bn`.

It's as if they assume that if you're using OCaml you're already an elite master of functional programming, who naturally knows what a "fold left" does.

I'm not an elite master of functional programming, but I've been around long enough to know that `fold_left` is basically the same as the [`reduce` function in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce).

It's a function that iterates through a list, applies a function to each value as it goes, and returns a single value.

So we can start to make sense of the signature of `fold_left`...

It takes three arguments:

1. The first arg, `f`, is a function which itself takes two args - the first or 'left' arg is the 'accumulated' value, and the second arg is the current value from the list as we iterate through. Whatever value you return from this function will be passed back into it as the left 'accumulated' value on the next iteration. When the list is exhausted the accumulated value will be returned from `fold_left`.
2. The second arg, `init` is an initial value. It is passed to `f` as the left 'accumulated' arg in the first step, when nothing has been otherwise accumulated yet.
3. Third arg is our list of values

Our pattern matching has already split the list into a head element `x` and remaining tail elements `xs`. So when we return:

```ml
Some (List.fold_left min x xs)
```

...we are passing the `min` function as `f` and `x` as `init`.

(We could use any element from the list as an initial value, but `x` was already handy here).

So `fold_left` is going to iterate through the list and `f` will return `min <accumulated> <current>`. So at each iteration step the accumulated value passed forward is the lowest value seen so far.

### Non-recursive?

I did wonder if perhaps the `fold_left` method does not count as non-recursive somehow, since no one else had suggested it. Even though we have not used `let rec` anywhere, maybe somewhere internally it is secretly recursive?

For fun I decided to try writing the reduce/fold function from scratch:

```ml
let reduce f init l =
  let acc = ref init in
  List.iter (fun el -> acc := f !acc el) l;
  !acc

(* we can directly substitute `reduce` for `List.fold_left` *)
let min_list l =
  match l with
  | [] -> None
  | x::xs -> Some (reduce min x xs)
```

...again, no `let rec` needed so I guess it counts as non-recursive.

Comment: Note that `List.length` is O(n) and thoroughly unnecessary. You don't need to knw the length of the whole list and whether it equals zero. You just need to know if it's empty which you can determine with pattern-matching which also eliminates the need for `List.hd`. `match l with [] -> None | x::xs -> List.fold_left min x xs`

Comment: @Chris good point! (I was OCaml beginner... still thinking in Python) I'll update the answer